# Separation and allocation of terms of Taylor series expansion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, taylor-series

How is it possible to "separate" the terms of the Taylor series expansion into single parts? I'm using this tool for variance analysis within managerial accounting.

I need to assign the single terms to the influencing factors.

This code could be the most simple presentation of the perpetual annuity.I want to show how the change in discount rate (b) and Cashflow (a) affects the value.

```
syms a b a1 b1 test;
test = evalin(symengine,'mtaylor(a/b , [a = a1, b = b1], 4)')
dtest = subs(test, [a, a1, b, b1],[40,150,0.01,0.12])-(a1/b1)
dtest2 = subs(dtest, [a1,b1],[150,0.12])
```

```
test =
 a1/b1 + (a - a1)/b1 - (a1*(b - b1))/b1^2 - ((a - a1)*(b - b1))/b1^2 + (a1*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3 - (a1*(b - b1)^3)/b1^4 + ((a - a1)*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3

dtest2 =
 545875/864
```

The following separation was manually made:

```
+(a - a1)/b1                  affected by delta cashflow
-(A1*(b - B1))/B1^2           affected by delta discount rate
-((a - a1)*(b - b1))/b1^2     affected by a mix of cashflow and disc. rate
+(a1*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3         affected by delta discount rate
-(a1*(b - b1)^3)/b1^4         affected by delta discount rate
+((a - a1)*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3   affected by a mix of cashflow and disc. rate

dtest2 -->>> The whole deviation
```

To reduce the remainder of the series expansion I want to expand up to an order of "200" e.g. That is why I want to separate and assign the single terms systematically and not manually.

Answer (score 1):

Find two successive Taylor Series Expansion, then subtract current series from previous, you'll get the additional single parts you need.

```
syms a b a1 b1 test test2;
n = 4 % Taylor Expansion degree
for i = 1:n
    test(i) = evalin(symengine,strcat('mtaylor(a/b , [a = a1, b = b1], ', num2str(i), ')'));
     if i == 1
        test2(i) = test(i);
     else
        test2(i) = test(i)-test(i-1);
     end
end

test2(1) = a1/b1
test2(2) = (a - a1)/b1 - (a1*(b - b1))/b1^2
test2(3) = (a1*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3 - ((a - a1)*(b - b1))/b1^2
test2(4) = ((a - a1)*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3 - (a1*(b - b1)^3)/b1^4
```

Filtering test2(2)

```
  filter = children(test2(2) + (a-a1) + (b-b1));
  filter = [ a, -a1, b, -b1, (a - a1)/b1, -(a1*(b - b1))/b1^2]
```

Ignore the 4 first array elements

```
filter(5) = (a - a1)/b1
filter(6) = -(a1*(b - b1))/b1^2
```

Filtering test2(3)

```
filter = children(test2(3) + (a-a1) + (b-b1));
filter = [ a, -a1, b, -b1, -((a - a1)*(b - b1))/b1^2, (a1*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3]
```

Ignore the 4 first array elements

```
filter(5) = -((a - a1)*(b - b1))/b1^2
filter(6) = a1*(b - b1)^2)/b1^3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and helpful response! That works fine, but I still have another question. How can I filter the equations regarding the number of influencial factors? 

For example:

test2(2) = (a - a1)/b1 - (a1*(b - b1))/b1^2 contains both (a - a1) and (b - b1). Consequently there is mixed influence and influce from change of "a" (Cashflow).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. How can i pick items out of the matrix filter regarding their content? 

For example, filter(5) if it contains (a-a1) and (b-b1).